# Best way to transfer data from View to complex controls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am building a control heavy application in wpf and I am trying use the best solution for various views (in terms of maintainability, scalability, etc).

Eg If I have a control on a main view and I want to bind data between them I use a dependency property.

My question is what is the best tool to use if I have a control (lets call it PaneControl) on a view (call it MainView), which itself contains a control (call it BasicControl) with a property on it which I want to pass to the main view.

Is there a way of passing the property from the BasicControl to the MainView without sending a command to PaneControl and then sending another command to MainView?

Comment: I have done some research and the approaches I am considering are: Routed Commands, Dependency Properties, Attached Properties or just normal Events. But I am trying to work out which is the best way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to transfer data from view to complex controls would be still Binding ElementName.

Here is a link to a page that explains how to use Binding ElementName.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.elementname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

If ElementName is not what you looking for then maybe x:Reference will help you out.

Take a look at this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee795380%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this sounds good. Can you give me an idea of why this is a good method?

Comment: Please take a look at the link I gave to you. There are already examples included. If you still have problems understanding it feel free to ask me about it.

Comment: Im just building a test project now to try it out

Comment: I feel that this looks like it might be the way to go, if it works that is!